# How do I disable the navigation bar shadow in iOS 6 for navigation bars with custom background images?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, shadow, ios6

It seems in iOS 6, a drop shadow is automatically added to the navigation bar even when you set a custom background image. I'm pretty sure this wasn't the case with iOS 5 as when I test the same code in the iOS 5 and 6 sim, the shadow appears in iOS 6 but not 5.

Does anyone know anything about this? Or how to enable/disable it?

Comment: iOS 6 is beta, pre-release software and I'm pretty sure that it's under NDA right now.

Comment: I would delete this question to avoid getting all the NDA comments and post it on the dev forums provided by Apple for pre-release software. https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios

Comment: Look at the UI customization session video again

Comment: David is right - the UI customisation video covers this exact topic.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Place this in your AppDelegate

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
// is IOS 7 and later
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

#### Swift version with updates from comments

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: NOTE: For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must also be set with the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method. If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless of the value of this property.

Comment: This is the right answer. `self.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;` doesn't have the same effect as the technique described in the answer.

Comment: You may want to add an autorelease to the [[UIImage alloc] init]

Comment: @BasHoltrop Autorelease? The Medieval period is gone. :)

Comment: The complete solution for >= iOS7 is   --  
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: This helped me for **iPhone 6 Plus simulator** `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Answer (score 57):

I know this has been solved with more complicated answers above, but this is the quickest and easiest way I hid the shadow under the navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: This works except during rotation, when the shadow returns.  Dima Korbin's answer above seems to be the most complete fix.

Comment: on iOS 7, this hides the status bar as well :(

Comment: Works well, I had trouble with the other answers on an iOS 6 app that also works on iOS 7 :)

Answer (score 25):

Note from the Apple dev docs on the subject of the `shadowImage` property:

> Discussion: The default value is nil, which corresponds to the default
>   shadow image. When non-nil, this property represents a custom shadow
>   image to show instead of the default. For a custom shadow image to be
>   shown, a custom background image must also be set with the
>   setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method. If the default background
>   image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless
>   of the value of this property.

So to use the nil UIImage hack you must also be setting a custom nav bar background image. This can be a nil image too, which results in a nice flat, clean 'metro' style nav bar :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 19):

Also you can try this:

```
controller.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];
```

controller is a UINavigationController.

Comment: Remember this only works in iOS 6. From UINavigationBar.h: 

    /* Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of the default shadow image...*/

    @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *shadowImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

Answer (score 7):

General, non-NDA-infringing answer:

If you don't want something sticking out of a layer, mask the layer to its bounds.

```
[self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Set the height explicitly to 44 (or 32 for landscape on iPhone) if that doesn't work on its own.

Comment: This solves the problem, but causes any UIBarButtonItems that "show touch on highlight" (the white glow) to be rendered incorrectly when tapped.

Comment: There is a better answer involving an image file, but that would be saying too much.

Comment: What property is that, layer?

Answer (score 6):

Setting the shadowImage to a null image does work, however, the way the solution is presented results in adding a property if the OS is earlier than iOS 6.

A better way to do something that is dependent on the existence of a property or method is:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar
respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)]) {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible solutions, the second of which is mentioned in other answers.

1. Add a single, transparent, pixel at the bottom of your navigation bar background image, making it 45pt tall. This disables the shadows in iOS 6.
2. Implement the following code:

   ```objectivec
   // Omit the conditional if minimum OS is iOS 6 or above
   if ([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setShadowImage:)]) {
       [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
   }
   ```

Source: [Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216), @27:15

Answer (score 2):

Since `self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];` not working, I've found an easy and workable way to remove the shadow of `UINavigationBar` in both iOS 6 AND iOS 5. Hope people who need can see this post.

All you have to do is prepare one background image that the height is 1 pixel larger than your navigation bar height (e.g. 320×45 for default UINavigationBar, 640×90 for 2x of course).

Then just use `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: ...]`, you will find shadow is replaced by that 1 pixel. cheers!

BTW I found Twitter has done the exactly same thing, if you unzip `Twitter.ipa` and look into `bg_nav_bar_events_dark.png`, the size is 320×47. They made their own shadow for 3 pixels :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so I'll add my information here.

Perhaps the above suggestions worked in the beta, but it does not seem to be the case now.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

The above does not work, neither do any of the other similar answers above. I have tried them all.

Clipping to bounds does work but doesn't give the result I want as I'd like other views to hang outside the nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this SO question when trying to get nav bars to look the same between iOS6 and iOS7.

The answer I found worked was simply to use:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *titleBarAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UINavigationBar appearance] titleTextAttributes]];
    [titleBarAttributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleBarAttributes];
```

ie: set the shadow offset to zero.

Answer (score 1):

How about the alternative way:

`UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .Black`

For the dark navigation bars iOS doesn't show the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've solved it by following:

```
CustomNavBar *navBar = (CustomNavBar *)self.navigationController.navigationBar;
        [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bar_gray.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        navBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc]init]; // this is what acctually removed the shadow under navigation bar
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0 this would look like this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage ()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```