# iOS UITabBar : Remove top shadow gradient line

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I implemented a custom UITabBar and I still have this gradient/shadow on top of it. 
I added

`[self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBottom.png"]];`

which is just changing the background but keeping the shadow gradient.

What am I doing wrong ? Is there anything to specify to get rid of it ?

What I have :

[image: top shadow]

What I want :

[image: without shadow]

Thank you.

Comment: **iOS 10.X** have some changes so please follow [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39858796/3752143).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try setting a 1x1 pixel transparent shadow image for the UITabBar:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentShadow.png"]];
```

Comment: I know how to deal with UITabBarItem shadow and already removed it. My concern is the UITabBar shadow (the big line on the top) that many apps succeeded to remove.

Comment: It worked, thanks :) (Also for people wondering transparentShadow.png is a 1x1 transparent image)

Comment: Thanks mate.. A lots of tries are solved by your code.. Thanks again.

Comment: Important: The value for "setShadowImage" is by default ignored, unless you also set a background image with setBackgroundImage. So you always have to set both! [From Apple docs]

Answer (score 127):

Similary in answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084331/how-do-i-disable-the-navigation-bar-shadow-in-ios-6-for-navigation-bars-with-cus) ... if You don't want to mess with any kind of 1x1 transparent image, this work's too:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]]; 
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

In swift:

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Don't forget: [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

Comment: @Roger: I'm not sure, is it necessary if You just need to remove the shadow?

Comment: Yes. I had to do it to fully remove the shadow otherwise it still displaying it.

Comment: @RogerFernandezGuri, actually it is not still displaying shadow, but what you see is a tab bar background colour. Instead of '[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];', you could also try setting the background colour...

Comment: If you are setting the tab bar background image to custom one, then add: '[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];'.

Comment: Upvoted this because you need to set the Background image too. The problem here is that setting the BG to an empty image makes the background transparent, at least if it's a translucent tab bar. Which might not be what you wanted.

Comment: Null image doesn't work in iOS 11, at least up to and including beta 6.

Comment: Worked on iOS 12. But doesn't work on iOS13 anymore! Have anyone tried? There's a new `tabBar.standardAppearance.shadowImage` but it doesn't work at all...

Comment: this solution and all other solutions will affect the uitabbaritem title font, it will not apply the custom font if you have one.

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 4**

```
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Just using `UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true` has the same effect.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift**

Try this for your custom tab bar. It will hide horizontal shadow line.

```
self.tabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "_hidesShadow")
```

**Objective C**

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

Comment: You can also add this in Interface Builder in the Identity Inspector pane for the UITabBar under the section "User Defined Runtime Attributes".  Hit the + to add a row and enter the _hidesShadow key and value.

Comment: This is accessing a private API, so could be cause for rejection and is likely to break in future versions of iOS.

Comment: I use the Swift code. It works for iOS 11 in 04,2018.

Answer (score 11):

This code works both iOS 13 and below

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = self.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear
    self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
} else {
    self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Comment: if you have custom font on the text of UITabBarItem it will get affected using your method

Answer (score 2):

Calling `[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:]` will customise all `UITabBar` instances in your app.

If you want to customize just one `UITTabBar`, you can do this:

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another easy to implement answer:

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Caveat is that this seems undocumented. Better use the - admittedly more tedious - methods above, setting shadow and background images.

Answer (score 2):

Just be setting image it will not remove the shadow line you have to set it's borderWidth to 0. here is the code

[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

[UITabBar appearance].layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;

[UITabBar appearance].clipsToBounds = true;

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your **AppDelegate** under **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
** Objective-C **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

** Swift **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is apple guideline for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage).

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the same look by following method.
1. Set the background bar tint colour to same as the main parent view background colour.
2.

```
this.TabBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackOpaque;
```

I used it in Xamarin, Please verify the Swift syntax.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to remove the shadow line on iOS 13 from a tab bar that has a custom font, then you have to apply it this way:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
   appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = ...
   appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = ...
   appearance.shadowColor = .clear
   tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller or view controllers or BasicViewController that most of the viewcontrollers inherit in the viewDidLoad just put these 2 lines:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_background"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent_shadow"]];
```

Be sure transparent_shadow@2x.png is an image 1x1 or 2x2 transparent and the tab_bar_background@2x.png is an image 640x100 as the bottom bar is 50px in height.

Works on iOS 9.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this on viewDidload.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "_hidesShadow")
}
```

It work for me

Answer (score -2):

In iOS 7 - this works:

```
[self.actionToolbar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny];
[self.actionToolbar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: it's "UITabBar" not UIToolBar.