# UIButton is too transparent

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIButton that sits ontop and is a subview of my UITabBar. But the button is still a bit transparent and I can see the lines from the tab bar through it. My button is created as so:

```
_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:(46.0)]];
[_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[_button setTintColor:[UIColor regularColor]];
[_button setAlpha:1.0];
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is the button disabled?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371343/ios-uitabbar-remove-top-shadow-gradient-line

Answer (score 0):

`[_button setAlpha:1.0];` Play around with setAlpha Property

Comment: no thats not it has something to do with tintColor from ios 7 forward

Comment: I believe property alpha controls the transparency of an object.

Comment: yes but at 1.0 it is at max if you read uiview docs but i can still see the tabbar top through my button

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your button is created in a storyboard. So if you try without the line "`_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`" it should not be transparent...