# Navigation Bar color

Tags: ios, swift, colors, background, uinavigationbar

I'm building an map app and have label with information of my route. I've set programmatically color of the label and navigation bar with the same hex. But while testing the app, I've noticed that they are different a bit. Can anybody tell me, what is wrong?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eeYP.png)

Main color is in Util class; nav bar appearance is set in app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method; label color is set in viewWillAppear of my map VC

`public static let mainColor = UIColor(fromHexCode: "#335E40")
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Util.mainColor
 infoLabel.backgroundColor = Util.mainColor`

Comment: UIColor(fromHexCode) does not exist. You should convert the hex value into rgba or create a method which would convert hex to rgba.

Comment: it didn't help. Colors are still different

Comment: Is the NavigationBar translucent? `navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true` (or false, see if this affects it)

Comment: @SunburstEnzo sure you can. If you use an extension you don't need to convert it to rgba ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you turn off the transition?

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

Comment: btw do you know how to get rid if this line between tab bar and label? [link](http://s13.postimg.org/xyho9bd7r/6e_YUE7c_Hix_E.jpg)

Comment: @KolyaBaidikov you are welcome.
No, sorry. I think you have to use a custom tab bar and do sth like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16334578/4906484